# Is using multiple spark windows a bad thing?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Recently, i started working on spark windows and trying to understand what happens under the hood in spark executors when applying these windowing functions.
My question is, since every window must be created using `partitionBy` function which means shuffling data across the cluster, is it normal to use multiple windows?

For example i have this dataframe :

```
    cli       date     item1   item2     
 --------- ---------- ------- -------
  1234567   20191030   A       D         
  1234567   20191030   B       D         
  1234567   20191029   A       E         
  1234567   20191026   A       F         
  7456123   20191026   C       D         
  7456123   20191025   C       F
```

The aim here is to calculate the frequency of each item for each client for every date based on history.

For example the client 1234567 at 20191030 used 4 item_1 from 20191030 and backwards so the frequency of A will be 3/4 and B is 1/4.

I chose to calculate these frequencies for each day by using windows since it calculates a value for each row, but I need to use three windows :

```
// This will give me the number of items used by a client
// in that day and all history.
val lByCliWindow = Window.partitionBy(col("cli")) 

// This will give me how many times a client used this exact item_1 A in
// that day and back in history (here my history is 120 days)
val lByCliItem1Window = Window
    .partitionBy(col("cli"), col("item_1"))
    .orderBy(to_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(LongType))
    .rangeBetween(-86400*120,0) 

// This will give me how many times a client used this exact item_3 F in
// that day and back in history (here my history is 120 days)
val lByCliItem2Window = Window
    .partitionBy(col("cli"), col("item_2"))
    .orderBy(to_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(LongType))
    .rangeBetween(-86400*120,0)
```

The expected output is :

```
  cli       date         frequency_item1              frequency_item2
 --------- ---------- ------------------------- --------------------------------
  1234567   20191030   Map(A -> 3/4, B -> 1/4)   Map(D -> 2/4, E -> 1/4, F 1/4)
  1234567   20191029   Map(A -> 2/2)             Map(E -> 1/2, F -> 1/2)            
  1234567   20191026   Map(A -> 1/1)             Map(F -> 1/1)
  7456123   20191026   Map(C -> 2/2)             Map(D -> 1/2, F -> 1/2)
  7456123   20191025   Map(C -> 1/1)             Map(F -> 1/1)
```

When i do `explain()` on this approach I can see so many exchange plans of `hashpartitioning` etc and that is very expectable since we are doing a `partitionBy` every time.

Giving that I have almost 30 variables this means 30 times partitioning of data. (This is a lot of shuffling)

What I want to understand is this approach normal? Will spark work on this partitioning on parallel (create multiple windows on the same time therefore partitioning the dataframe in multiple different ways at the same time) or sequentially?

Can we use multiple windows? what is more costly the `groupBy` shuffle or `partitionBy` windows shuffle?

Thank you for your replies and don't hesitate to propose different approach for calculating frequencies using windows.

Comment: Can you provide the output you expect? Also, a string version (instead of an image) of your data would help a lot ;-)

Comment: Hello Oli, Thnx for the upVote, I did what you recommended. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that involves only one window. I'll explain with comments.

```scala
// The columns you are interested in
val items = df.columns.filter(_ startsWith "item")

// collect_list aggregation. It avoid duplicates. We will group by cli and date.
val aggs = items.map(c => collect_list(col(c)) as c)

// A window over "cli" and ordered by date.
val win = Window.partitionBy("cli").orderBy("date")

// A UDF that computes the frequencies you want
// It takes as input a seq of seq because of the first aggregation we do
val compute_freqs = udf((s : Seq[Seq[String]]) => {
    val flat_s = s.flatten
    val total = flat_s.size
    flat_s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size.toDouble / total)
})

// for each item, we collect the values over the window, and compute the frequency
val frequency_columns = items
    .map(item => compute_freqs(collect_list(col(item)) over win)
                       .alias(s"frequency_$item"))

// Then we use everything
val result = df
    .groupBy("cli", "date")
    .agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail : _*)
    .select((Seq("cli", "date").map(col) ++ frequency_columns) :_*)
    .orderBy($"cli", $"date" desc)
```

And here is the result:

```
scala> result.show(false)
+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|cli    |date    |frequency_item1       |frequency_item2                 |
+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|1234567|20191030|[A -> 0.75, B -> 0.25]|[D -> 0.5, F -> 0.25, E -> 0.25]|
|1234567|20191029|[A -> 1.0]            |[F -> 0.5, E -> 0.5]            |
|1234567|20191026|[A -> 1.0]            |[F -> 1.0]                      |
|7456123|20191026|[C -> 1.0]            |[D -> 0.5, F -> 0.5]            |
|7456123|20191025|[C -> 1.0]            |[F -> 1.0]                      |
+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i fprgot to mention that i want to avoid udfs coz my database is very huge (1 billion record) so serializeing all that data is very costly and i want to only use spark sql inbuilt functions. But i really appreciate your approach i will try it and get back to you but meanwhile can you upvote the question so we can get more ideas please?

Comment: I understand why you would want to avoid UDFs. If you use spark 2.4, there might be a way around it. But note that even though UDFs are expensive, it's nothing compared to shuffling the data dozens of times.

Comment: ps: 1 billion is not that much for Spark. This code would probably take very little time. Try it and let me know. If it's not fast enough, we'll think of something else ;) Also, note that not everything is going to be serialized. Only one record per (client, date) tuple.

Comment: Hello Oli, I tried your solution which resulted in an Exception "MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 1" which is obviously related to memory overhead i tried increasing memory to 32Gb per executor for 20 executors of 2 cores. They produced 12GB of shuffle write and then in the the next 200 tasks it fails with that exception while doing shuffle read. I am confused how can it fail for just 12 gb of shuffle is that too much?

Comment: In general that's totally manageable. How much disk space do you have on your executors?

Comment: To be honest i don't know how to see how much disk i have..but what i remarked is that there is shuffle spill only  on memory and not a single Ko on the disk. I tried playing with spark.shuffle.memoryFraction and with spark.memory.fraction to give more space for shuffling but in vain. How can i force it to shuffle on disk though?